# IEnumerable T4 Templates

Tags: c#, .net, interface, t4

I'm working on some code-generation stuff - using T4 RuntimTemplates.
I do have more than one template and I "store" them in an `IEnumerable` list.

My problem is that I want to iterate through the templates using `.WriteAllText()` which is a virtual method.

I thought, that it might be the easiest way to create an interface with the definition of `.WriteAllText()` and declare it in the partial class..

```
public partial class SolutionTemplateRunTime : SolutionTemplateRunTimeBase, ICodegenerationTemplate
{
```

This works till I store or update the template ;-) . The partial class (the code behind cs) of the template gets updated and the interfaces declaration is gone.

```
public partial class SolutionTemplateRunTime : SolutionTemplateRunTimeBase
{
```

Is there a solution to handle that? Its kind of annoying to redeclare the interface whenever I update the template..

Hope you can help..

Greetz Iki

Comment: add the `WriteAllText` method to `SolutionTemplateRunTimeBase`

Comment: SolutionTemplateRunTimeBase  get recreated too.. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of `partial` - the idea is that exactly the kind of changes you want to do are done in a separate file - one that isn't generated.

Just create a new `cs` file, with a declaration like this:

```
public partial class SolutionTemplateRunTime : ICodegenerationTemplate
{
  ...
}
```

When compiling the code, the compiler will merge all partial declarations of the same class - this includes whatever interfaces the class implements etc.